# React animation / ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs

How would you make the following link - a spinner - work with reactjs

http://codepen.io/awesome/pen/znGwr

I am using webpack:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
```

I know the css is working from other settings.

I have tried the following, using the same css file(copy paste into local css ).

Updated: I do "return" the element, but did not write it in here. Felix Kling, thanks for noting this.

ES6:

```
render(){
      return
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="spinner" >
          <div key='test' className="spinner"></div>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
}
```

or

```
render(){
          return
          <div key='test' className="spinner"></div>
}
```

This(both) just gives me a circle and no animation.

Comment: This question is very confusing.  Since `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is intended to allow you to use CSS transitions when components enter/leave the DOM, I assume you're asking about the best transition to use for when the spinner enters/leaves the DOM, but even that is pretty vague.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Hi Michael and thanks for you reply. I am clearly missing something regarding react and animation. But how would you put http://codepen.io/awesome/pen/znGwr into a react render() I have tried to update the question.

Comment: There is nothing special you have to do, just render the element with the correct class name. The problem with your second (and first actually) example is that you don't **`return`** the element, so it renders nothing.

Comment: I mean - it works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/dsxt25cs/  Is it possible that you were copying over the uncompiled SCSS instead of the compiled CSS?

Comment: Yes, that is very possible :-| That was it. Can I give you an "Answer" for this?

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked in your comments for an answer...

I believe the problem is that you were copying over the uncompiled SCSS instead of the compiled CSS.

Hope this helps!  :D